# VS Code can't open ipynb file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Have everyone already had this problem, where VS Code keeps loading all the time and won't open a `ipynb` file? I've tried to use python 3.7 but same problem. Also tried to reinstall both VS Code and Anaconda, no success.

[image]

Here is my environment data:

- VS Code version: 1.49.0
- Python extension version:v2020.8.108011
- OS and version: Ubuntu 20.04
- Python version (& distribution if applicable, e.g. Anaconda): Anaconda python 3.8.3
- Type of virtual environment used: using conda base environment
- Value of the python.languageServer setting: "Pylance"
- ipython version: 7.16.1
- jedi version: 0.17.1
- ipykernel version: 5.3.2

Comment: Could you try opening the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and run `Python: Create Blank New Jupyter Notebook`, do you get an error doing so?

Comment: It keeps the same, loading and not open the file.

Comment: Update droped and now it works fine again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their official GitHub page, they are tracking this issue already. There is also a solution (kind of) right now. You have to maximize the terminal panel below and then restore the panel size (basically max and min with the arrow button). Then the Notebook loads and everything works fine. :D

The workaround was in this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13901#issuecomment-691625412

Not perfect but at least all the features are there and I can work with my notebooks again :)

Comment: Pretty broken, I can't believe this is still busted in July 2021, I just installed Visual Studio code, saw the abysmal ratings on the Jupyter extension and well, run into the same problem. Can't Microsoft fix this in almost a year???

Comment: @MarkusBawidamann, seems to be some kind of regression. It was working recently.

Comment: I'm also surprised they haven't fixed it yet. I haven't used it in some time because I'm working on a JupyterHub/JupyterLab server for my university. Someone further down this section mentioned the extension is deprecated. Maybe that's why.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved (for now) this problem by downgrading jupyter extension to previous version.

Go to Extension (in the left vertical panel) > select Jupyter > click the down arrow of the Uninstall button > then you get "install another version" tooltip > click it > select other version > reload vscode

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue after the latest update. You can try importing the notebook by pressing ctrl+shift+p/command+shift+p and run *Import Jupyter Notebook*.

Comment: same here, i am having the same exact problem, anyone has solutions?

Comment: No solutions yet, just partial ones. I've opened an [issue at GiHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13901) and there are many other similar ones.

Answer (score 1):

For me maximizing and resetting the terminal panel didn't work whereas uninstalling and reinstalling the VSCode Python extension solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem since the last update.
For now, in case you still want to use VSCode, you can 'convert to python script' and run it in interactive mode (right click on the notebook, and choose that).
It doesn't solve the issue, but make it possible currently to use your notebooks in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior. Downgrades of Jupyter extension works for me
[(screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHpTh.png)

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, double-clicking just stopped working for me for some reason.
Try right-clicking the *.ipynb file in the VS explorer panel and select 'Open in Notebook Editor'

Answer (score -3):

Download the jupyter Notebook extention in VS code.
and than click the .ipynb file.

After clicking .ipynb file vs code will preview.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyiNM.png)

Comment: Jupyter notebook extention for VS Code has been depreciated. It's part of Python extention now.